# Salesforce Managed Package Custom Settings

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

I have an hierarchical custom settings in my salesforce managed app i'm developing, I want to know is it possible to package the default custom settings data during packaging? or if not do i have to write any apex code to populate them during install? any link or relevant samples are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the Default Value that appears under the General Options for each custom field definition?

Failing that you have two options:

1. Use a [post install script](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm) to set the Org Defaults after the managed package is installed.
2. Wrap all usage of the custom settings in Apex in your own class. If you detect a null value, return the default value.

I use the latter approach, as you can update the default values in the class without potentially overwriting any org defined values with updates etc...

Incidentally, check out [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com). It is a great place for asking Salesforce specific questions.